# I am trying to create a buy system using a button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a system, which, displays the amount of money you have, displays the cost of what you are purchasing, has a button which, when clicked takes away an amount of your money, and increases the amount it takes away each click, however, the button just doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="buyA.js">
    </script>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="money">
        <script>
        document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = "Money: " + money;
        </script>
    </p>
    <p id="cost">
        <script>
        document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "Cost: " + buyA;
        </script>
    </p>
    <input id="Purchase" type="button" value="Purchase" onclick="BuyA();"/>
</body>
</html>

var money = 1000;
var buyA = 500;

function BuyA() {
    if (money >= buyA) {
        money - buyA;
        buyA + 250;
    }
    else {
        window.alert("Not Enough Money")
    }
}
```

Comment: Try these functions in sequence: `owner.hireKiller().getMoney(person).deliverMoney().payback()`

Comment: `money - buyA;` and `buyA + 250;` are statements that do not do anything. You need to use these values _somehow_.

Answer (score 1):

You're putting your scripts in the wrong place. Plus you're making mistakes on assigning values (`money` and `buyA`).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="buyA.js">
    </script>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    
    <!-- Put your scripts here -->
    <script>
    var money = 1000;
    var buyA = 500;

    function BuyA() {
        if (money >= buyA) {
            // deduct the money
            // money - buyA;
            money = money - buyA;
            
            // increase the price
            // buyA + 250;
            buyA = buyA + 250;
            
            // update the values
            document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = "Money: " + money;
            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "Cost: " + buyA;
        }
        else {
            window.alert("Not Enough Money")
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="money"></p>
    <p id="cost"></p>
    <script>
    // update the values
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = "Money: " + money;
    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "Cost: " + buyA;
    </script>
    <input id="Purchase" type="button" value="Purchase" onclick="BuyA();"/>
</body>
</html>
```